# Format of docker remote api image date created field

Tags: date, docker

Just wondering who might know what the number on the "created" attribute of the json response for images might mean.

Obviously its something to do with the day of creation, but I'm not sure how to format it, it doesnt look like a standard timestamp, does it represent "days ago" or a specific date?

How can I format this?

eg `Created: 1402148149`

Comment: please read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Answer (score 0):

As was stated by @Melbourne2991 that is a UNIX timestamp. Seconds since the epoch of Jan 1 1970. However, you will find that the Docker API is inconsistent about how it reports dates. `/containers/json` will give you the created field for all the returned containers as a UNIX timestamp, but `/containers/DOCKERID/json` will give you the same field in ISO 8601 format. Just something to consider when writing your code.